# what is response in FB.getLoginStatus

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, status

To detect the facebook user online/offline status we use the method FB.getLoginStatus method.
But, what does the paramater("response") mean and where does it come from in the below code snippet 
the parameter response mean in the line " FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) "

```
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                 // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                 // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                 // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                 // request, and the time the access token 
                 // and signed request each expire
                 var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                 var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                 console.log('User logged in and autenticated');
              } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                 // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                 // but has not authenticated your app
                 console.log('User logged in, but not autorized');
              } else {
                 // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                 console.log('User not logged in');
              }
       }, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a function to be called when the Facebook API has completed retrieving a response from the server. It passes the response object to the function which you specify. A typical response would be:

```
{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}
```

See [facebook javascript docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) for more info